# UI elements in ListView stop responding

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.forms

I have standard UI elements in rows within a ListView. When I scroll the list too far away from the UI elements and scroll back, they stop responding and the clicks fall through to the cell below.

Any ideas why this might happen?

If I don't scroll away from a UI element, it works. Also, if I scroll up and down a few times, elements will start working again.

It can't be my click handlers failing to fire because a picker will open up - and they don't need client code to open them.

I don't have an adapter. This is via Xamarin. I was hoping someone with some deeper knowledge of Android might have some insight.

Comment: can you post your adapter code here? along with the xml for your row item. Are you using the ViewHolder pattern? if not, try looking into that.

Comment: @momoja Sorry, it's written in Xamarin, which doesn't use adapters.

Comment: Xamarin Forms doesn't use an adapter.  Xamarin Android does.  Regardless, asking us to help debug code requires that you POST the relevant code is the first place.

Comment: @Jason I'll have a poke around in Reflector.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/viewcell) article and discovered that rendering a cell can be extremely simple. Then I found the `ViewCellRenderer` source code in Visual Studio. I copied it, hacked away a load of stuff and the bug has gone.

There was some suspicious stuff regarding handling long presses. Perhaps one day I will go back in and try and find exactly what was causing the problem.

It doesn't seem to have broken so far. I'll update it if it goes wrong.

This is what I'm left with...

```
public class ResponseViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
    protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
    {
        if (convertView is ViewCellContainer container)
        {
            container.DisposeView();
        }

        return new ViewCellContainer(context, (ViewCell) item);
    }
}

internal class ViewCellContainer : ViewGroup
{
    readonly ViewCell viewCell;
    readonly IVisualElementRenderer viewRenderer;

    public ViewCellContainer(Context context, ViewCell viewCell) : base(context)
    {
        this.viewCell = viewCell;

        viewRenderer = Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(viewCell.View, Context);

        Platform.SetRenderer(viewCell.View, viewRenderer);

        AddView(viewRenderer.View);
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        var width = Context.FromPixels(r - l);
        var height = Context.FromPixels(b - t);

        Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(viewRenderer.Element, new Rectangle(0.0, 0.0, width, height));

        viewRenderer.UpdateLayout();
    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        var size = MeasureSpec.GetSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        var sizeRequest = viewRenderer.Element.Measure(Context.FromPixels(size), double.PositiveInfinity, MeasureFlags.IncludeMargins);

        int measuredHeight = (int)Context.ToPixels((viewCell.Height > 0.0) ? viewCell.Height : sizeRequest.Request.Height);

        SetMeasuredDimension(size, measuredHeight);
    }

    public void DisposeView()
    {
        Platform.SetRenderer(viewCell.View, null);

        RemoveView(viewRenderer.View);

        viewRenderer.View.Dispose();
    }
}
```